# How to access the image file in uploads folder from views in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Carrierwave for image upload. I uploaded image to myapp/uploads folder not to public folder. Now in views I want to display the image So i used

```
<img id="img_prev" width=300 height=300 src="<%= @admin.admin_photo.url%>" alt="your image" class="img-thumbnail hidden"/>
```

But the image url is not loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `image_tag` helper:

```
<%= image_tag @admin.admin_photo.url, id: 'img_prev', width: 300, height: 300, alt: 'your image', class: 'img-thumbnail hidden' %>
```

Comment: Yes...But how to access the image in uploads folder that is not in public directory

Comment: @Emmanu I skipped that it wasn't in the public folder. You need to activate static assets. This can solve the problem: in `config/environments/production.rb` or `config/environments/development.rb` you need to set `config.serve_static_assets = true`

Comment: Then you need to restart server

Comment: @demir `serve_static_assets` config won't help it will still serve files only from public directory. This configuration only tells that rails should serve your static files from public folder, that it won't be handled by some webserver eg Apache or Nginx.